# _attributes vs _data for Ember Models

Tags: model, ember-data

So, I'm having a problem when I click an employment object and log the contents of eventRef (of type: object with an array inside) it shows properly, but once I save it and log contents, they appear as null,null. Inspecting the Ember Model, I'm able to find that the _attributes are reset from the eventIds to null,null, however, the eventIds can still be found within _data.

What is the difference between _attributes and _data. Is there a way to refresh the attributes from the _data?

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBkPf.jpg

Answer (score 0):

When working with Ember objects, you generally want to use `.get(..)` to access their properties, as that will give you reliable behavior and fire appropriate Ember hooks. There are no guarantees that what you see in private properties such as `_attributes` or `_data` are up to date as far as bindings go. Instead, try logging `employmentObject.get('appliedEventList.eventRef')` (assuming I understood the format of your object correctly).

Edit: It occurs to me that you might already know all this.

Comment: I am doing that. However, the problem is, the data in it logs to [null,null]. meaning it gets the data from the attributes instead of from _data where the fields are defined. Which makes it confusing. Why is the object returning the contents from _attributes instead of from _data?

Comment: When you save (I'm assuming your using Ember-data here), it does a round trip to/from your server and replaces the object with whatever your server returned. Are you sure that your server returns an object with eventRef filled in with values? Also, what happens if you log `employmentObject.get('appliedEventList.eventRef').objectAt(0)`?